# MODX. Пакет Login, регистрация пользователя. Как сделать проверку на одинаковый логин и пароль?

Tags: modx, регистрация, login

Я реализовала регистрацию пользователей по этой инструкции https://modx.ru/novosti-i-stati/article/63/. Но мне нужно дополнить регистрацию проверкой, чтоб логин и пароль не совпадали, и, если совпадают, вывести сообщение об ошибке. Нигде не нашла ни ответа на свой вопрос, ни понятной документации по пакету Login. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте параметр `preHooks`,создайте сниппет, например, `uniqueLogin`, укажите в параметре `&preHooks`=`uniqueLogin`, а в сниппете следующее:

```
<?php
$login = $hook->getValue('login');
$password = $hook->getValue('password');
if($login !== $password) return true;
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как теперь в чанке вывести ошибку, если логин совпадает с паролем?

Comment: а, все, разобралась